# How to make an angular component accept one value from one of two lists?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, union-types

I have an angular component that needs to accept a value that is contained in one of two lists.

Ex:

```
  @Input()
  public type!: enumA | enumB;
```

But this doesn't work if the enums don't have distinct values and I don't like linking them together like that. I would also prefer to not use string enums. What is the best way to clearly determine I received enumA.Foo or enumB.Foo?

I'm using enums in this example but am not tied to them.

Comment: Please share mode code than that. Yes, typescript properties can have union types but from the code you've shared it's really hard to tell what the problem might be.

Comment: The problem is you can't tell which list the input value is from. If enumA has x=1 and enumB has y=1, you don't know which enum the value is from.

Answer (score 0):

So, unfortunately this is kinda just how enums work.  Enums are just a way to give names to number values so they have some meaning. In the end they are just numbers and what you are trying to ask here is essentially "tell me which array the number 3 came from" - there's no way to tell if all you have is `3` to go off of.

Consider the following TS code, or [see it on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQUwdgrgtqlQgsA3gKGO4B5MJgF5gBGAGjQwBUB3Ae32ACZSNhyALAJxFwIGY0BfFGXDRY0AELIy6bNyJMKNOo2ksOXOn2CDgaAG4BDdsAAeALjEJgAH0uSCIqOIB0bTiADcQ4AGNqYAGdqABsQZ2DqAHMACgAXAE8ABxBqADNTYlMASi80P0CQsIiYhOS0u0zHcSygA)

```ts
 enum enumA {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
 }

  enum enumB {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
 }
 
 var x: enumA | enumB = enumB.Three;

 console.log(typeof x, x);

 console.log(typeof enumB, enumB)
```

That will log out:

```
"number",  3 

"object",  {
  "1": "One",
  "2": "Two",
  "3": "Three",
  "One": 1,
  "Two": 2,
  "Three": 3
}
```

Enums just don't provide enough information to be back to trace anything back to their source like you are hoping for.

If you must use enums the best you might be able to do is add a 2nd property to pass the entire enum and the value as separate fields, like this:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQUwdgrgtqlQgsA3gKGO4B5MJgF5gBGAGjQwBUB3Ae32ACZSNhyALAJxFwIGY0BfFGXDRY0AELIy6bNyJMKNOo2ksOXOn2CC0ASzAAXEOwBmAQwDGuAJIBxcMd0WAonCkYA2gGcAXMDgARsYAun5eBuz6AOYCaCgmEGAWBrrUYMBG4QA85HR2DpEucAB8ABQANrrhfuTEwABuZuV+ANYgAJ7UJiwAlKgYFmle1OUgAHTl1FEVVQZ1jeU9ANwoOpkGpSIIdQBEsjvLwEA)

```ts
 enum enumA {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
 }

  enum enumB {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
 }

 interface IGenericEnum {
   [s: number]: string
 }
 
function test<T = IGenericEnum>(list: T, val: keyof T){
   console.log(list, val);
}

test(enumA, "One");
```

It's not perfect since you only get the values of the enum, and if your enums are identically you won't be able to tell them apart, but it at least will give you a bit more information and it will still be strongly typed.  Attempting `test(enumA, "Foo")` will give an error for example.

Comment: I don't have to use enums, is there a better solution with something else?

Comment: Yes for sure!  Check out this article: https://maxheiber.medium.com/alternatives-to-typescript-enums-50e4c16600b1